# select only ONE column from the query: "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `DB`"?

Tags: mysql, sql, show

is possible select only ONE column from the QUERY: "SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `DB`" ??

I want select ONLY 1 or 2 columns from result obtained in the QUERY:

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `DB`
```

I need ALL tables of this DB, but I no need columns as

**Max_data_length,  Index_length,   Data_free,  Auto_increment, etc...**

is possible get only ONE column from this multiple columns result in only 1 QUERY?

Comment: Which columns do you actually want?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can query from `information_schema.tables` instead of showing table status. It will give you same information you need

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  , DATA_LENGTH FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = DATABASE();
```

Comment: many thanks by your help.

now run perfect:

 **SELECT `Name`, `Update_time`, `Auto_increment` FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB';**

:-)

Comment: In fact, SHOW TABLE STATUS gets its data from the same table in information_schema.

Comment: `SELECT UPDATE_TIME, TABLE_NAME FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'DB' ORDER BY UPDATE_TIME DESC LIMIT 1;` (without _STR_TO_DATE()_ :-s )